# I have a scientific research invitation letter, what kind of visa I need

Tags: visas, schengen, france

I have a scientific research invitation letter from a french research institute.

However, the purpose of this invitation is to make presentations as a part of Ph.D application process.

so if I am accepted after this presentations as a Ph.D student, then I will proceed with a long stay research visa.

But my question is what is the appropriate kind of visa that I should apply for now, for this short stay visit.

Comment: What's your citizenship. How long are you staying. Are you going to be paid. Is that invitation a formal [euraxess](http://ec.europa.eu/euraxess/index.cfm/services/scientificVisa) hosting agreement.

Comment: I have a feeling this question might be better suited for expats.SE  as it is not really about travel?

Comment: As it stands it is impossible to answer or decide. I am voting to close as unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply for a normal, short stay visa. The purpose of your trip (question number 21) should be "OTHER" and you should type "Academic Conference"; as none of the choices apply. These are:

- Tourism
- Business
- Visiting family or friends
- Cultural
- Sports
- Official Visit
- Medical Reasons
- Study
- Transit
- Airport Transit
- Other

You can provide the invitation letter as part of your supporting documents; along with the normal requirements for such a visit:

1. Proof of financial means / support
2. Hotel accommodations for the period of your stay
3. Travel reservation for the period of your stay
4. Insurance suitable for Schengen visa purposes and valid for the period of your stay.
5. Valid passport
6. Letter of employment (if applicable)

Comment: This might or might not be the correct answer; if it is then the question is a duplicate of http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39446/attending-an-academic-conference-is-what-type-of-travel but it depends on all the questions I asked.