# Type of Visa for attending a conference in Norway

Tags: visas, norway, conferences

I intend to travel to Oslo next month from India to present a paper at an academic conference. The University won't pay me for this. Given that Norway doesn't have a provision for Conference Visa, should I apply for a Business Visa under short-term Visitor's visa? Should I specify the purpose of travel as 'Business' or 'Other', given that I am attending an academic and not a business conference?

Comment: Perhaps [Attending an academic conference is what type of travel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39446/attending-an-academic-conference-is-what-type-of-travel) is a closer match. (That the questions are about different countries does not matter, though: France, Portugal and Norway are all in the Schengen area and so follow harmonized rules about visas and visa applications).