# Which type of Schengen visa i should apply for?

Tags: france, schengen-visas, applications

I'm a Graduate student in F1 visa, Going on a college trip to France for 10 days, I will be attending conference (part of my trip). Which visa type should I apply for?

Comment: And going to the races, too, eh? <g>

Comment: Couple days of class at the hotel and will be attending a conference and some sightseeing

Comment: Sounds like a great trip.

Comment: should I apply for a student visa or a tourist visa?

Comment: @jagan I believe David’s comment about ‘going to the races’ is related to the ‘formula-one’ tag on your question :-) I suspect you meant to choose the ‘F1-visas’ tag

Comment: A student visa is generally for someone who will enroll in a school in the country that issues the visa.  In no case will a student visa be indicated for a trip to an academic conference.

Answer (score 1):

You should apply for a type C short-term visa. Unlike some other countries, the Schengen area does not have strictly defined visa categories. When applying, categories are there to help processing, your visa will not mention for example “study” or “tourism”. Since Schengen does not have an 'Academic' category, you should select the category that best represents the main purpose of your trip.

There is a discussion of this topic here [Attending an academic conference is what type of travel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39446/attending-an-academic-conference-is-what-type-of-travel/39453#39453)