# What type of visa should I apply for attending an academic conference in France?

Tags: india, schengen-visas, france, conferences

What type of visa should I apply for attending an academic conference in France?

I am a postdoctoral candidate in an institute in India. I will be attending a conference in France. When I tried to apply for a visa, I could not see an appropriate visa application type. None of them seems to fit perfectly.

I asked the conference organisers, and they suggested to talk to the embassy. I have sent an email, but there wasn't any response from the embassy.

Edit : I am attaching the screenshots of all options that are showing in the visa application form.

It is not clear which one of them are correct choice.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: AFAIK this activity is permitted under the ‘C’ type short-stay visa. What options does the application present you with?

Comment: @Traveller Many people are surprised by this but every activity is permitted under a type C visa as there is no other short-stay visa beside the airport transit visa. If you want to work (the one type of activity that is restricted) and you are not covered by [an exemption](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F2728#6), you need to secure a permit *before* applying for the visa and that visa will still be a regular type C Schengen visa.

Comment: @Traveller Please see the edited version.. I have added screenshots of the options

Comment: @Praphulla Koushik The visa *type* is a short-stay (C) visa. As mentioned in the answers to your question, the best fit amongst the options to state your reason for applying (*main purpose of stay*) is Business, or Other. The visa-issuing authority will be able to tie that up with your paperwork proving your intended attendance at the conference.

Answer (score 6):

> What type of visa to apply for attending a academic conference in France?

A short-stay visa. See https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en/web/france-visas/short-stay-visa for details:

> It is also issued to persons entering to France to take part in short training programmes, internships, **conferences** and corporate meetings, or to engage in remunerated activities (whatever the form), not exceeding 90 days.

[Choose](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/39493/1810) business -> scientific event, as checkmarked below:

[image]

Comment: Even in short term visa there are some options... Please see the edited question..It is not clear which one is applicable..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik choose business https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/39493/1810

Comment: Wouldn't the scientist/researcher option be more appropriate here. Or does it mean something else?

Answer (score 4):

The rule is surprisingly simple: For a stay under 90 days, you need a Schengen visa (type C visa or uniform short-stay visa). There is only one type of visa and it covers all purposes (e.g. on subsequent trips, if you get a multiple-entry visa; the point is more academic for single-entry visas).

Annex II of the Schengen Visa Code provides a “non-exhaustive” list of supporting documents that includes this:

> for journeys undertaken for political, scientific, cultural, sports or religious events or other reasons:
>
> — invitation, entry tickets, enrolments or programmes stating (wherever possible) the name of the host organisation and the length of stay or any other appropriate document indicating the purpose of the journey;

That's very broad but it does seem to fit an academic conference. You could therefore choose “Business/Cultural, artistic, scientific and sports event” in the website menu. [On the official form](https://france-visas.gouv.fr/fr_FR/web/france-visas/formulaires), you could also simply check “other” (“autre”) and write “academic conference”.

Comment: Even in short term visa there are some options... Please see the edited question..It is not clear which one is applicable..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I see. Those are not really different types of visa and it's unfortunate whoever made the online removed the “other” option that's present on the official form. I will expand on that in my answer.