# Attending an academic conference in Spain. Where should I provide (or do I provide) details of my accommodation?

Tags: schengen-visas, spain, conferences

I am an F1 student of Indian nationality pursuing my doctoral studies in USA. I am trying to fill blocks 30 and (or) 31 of the Schengen visa application form to attend a conference in Spain. From [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39446/attending-an-academic-conference-is-what-type-of-travel) post, I came to know that the travel type should be Business. My questions are the following:

(1) Since there is no inviting 'person' (rather the inviting 'conference'?) should block 30 be filled? If yes, should I be providing details of the committee chair (I already asked for his consent to share details) ? 
(2) If I am filling in block 31, where do I specify my accommodation details? 
(3) In block 32, should I mention that the cost of traveling is covered by myself (my university/PI would be sponsoring my travel and accommodation).

Thank you.

[image: block 30]
[image: block 31]
[image: block 32]

Comment: Did you notice that the last sentence of 30 reads "If not applicable, name of hotel(s) [...]"? I'm not an expert, but if I were to fill out this form, I'd put the accomodation details into box 30, the details of the conference organizers into box 31 ("Name of inviting organisation").