# What type of Schengen visa should I apply for if I will be participating in an academic conference?

Tags: visas, germany, schengen-visas, business-travel, conferences

I am going to attend an academic workshop from Nov 11, 2023, to Nov 15, 2023, at a research institute in Germany. I have a formal invitation letter from this research institute and they are going to cover my travel expenses and accommodation. I plan to stay there from Nov 11 to Nov 17.

What type of visa should I choose Business or Tourism visa?

I think Business fits but since I am going to be staying 4 more days in addition to the conference days, does this make it a tourism visa? - I am trying to be precise and honest.

I am a graduate student and a TA at a university in the Middle East.

Comment: [Attending an academic conference is what type of travel in Portugal?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39446/attending-an-academic-conference-is-what-type-of-travel-in-portugal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no separate visas for tourism or business, it’s the same visa and the same application form.

What the application form asks for is the “main purpose(s) of the journey”, and I suppose this is the conference (would you take those extra days if you didn’t come for the conference?), so this would be “Business”.

You could also check both of you feel they have equal importance in your trip, but this may have an influence on the requirements in terms of justification and documentation.

Comment: Application for Schengen visas are done through TLScontact which has been officially appointed by the German Consulate to collect visa applications on its behalf in some Middle East countries. To reserve an appointment I have to choose either Business or Tourism.

Comment: Thanks. I will include that in my VIDEX Form